# Swift custom segue on condition

Tags: swift, xcode6, segue

I'm trying to conditionally execute a segue based on whether or not a users login information is correct.

I have a modal segue from my login View Controller to a new Navigation Controller.

I've tried pretty much every suggestion I've come across and nothing has seemed to work.  Using Sift and Xcode 6.

```
import UIKit

import AudioToolbox

class ViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField: UITextField!

   @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!

   @IBOutlet weak var incorrectCredentialLabel: UILabel!

   @IBAction func loginAction(sender: UIButton) {

       var username = "test"
       var password = "code"

       println("Username: " + usernameTextField.text)
       println("Password: " + passwordTextField.text)

       if usernameTextField.text == username &&
          passwordTextField.text == password {

          usernameTextField.resignFirstResponder()
          passwordTextField.resignFirstResponder()

          println("Login Status: success")

       self.shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier("loginSegue", sender: nil)

    } else {

         usernameTextField.resignFirstResponder()
         passwordTextField.resignFirstResponder()

         AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(1352)
        /*AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)*/

         incorrectCredentialLabel.text = "username or password is incorrect"
         incorrectCredentialLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()

         println("Login Status: failed")
    }
}

 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
 }

 override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
     super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
     // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me.  Two UITextFields and a UIButton along with a modal segue from VC to VC2:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    let userName = "John"
    let passCode = "123"

    @IBOutlet weak var Name: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var Pass: UITextField!
    @IBAction func tapButton(sender: UIButton) {

        if self.Name.text == "John" && self.Pass.text == "123" {

         performSegueWithIdentifier("nextView", sender: self)
        }
    }

    //ViewController lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.Name.delegate = self
        self.Pass.delegate = self

    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working; when I input the incorrect username and password in the text fields the program still segue's.

Comment: hmm,I just went back to my test file and it works only with the correct pass.  Let m post to Github and get you a link.

Comment: https://github.com/StevenRosenberg99/TestView/tree/master  If entering the wrong passcode works, let me know.  Name = "John", pass = "123"

Comment: well, did you try it?

Comment: Haven't gotten a chance to code in awhile. I created a new project using that code to initiate the segue and entering the incorrect username/passcode still passes on to the next VC.

Comment: Got it to work.  I was triggering my segue from the button to the next VC, but linking the segue from VC to VC worked.

Answer (score 0):

well this is my first time i hope it will help

i did an offline Signup metho for triyng but i think the objective is the same

my code for conditional segue was this

```
@IBAction func LoginPressed(sender: UIButton) {

/*previously assigned by the app owner for the customer it is saved in the app code so it is in the phone memory(?)*/
        if RutField.text == "243338743"  && CodigoField.text == "1104"{
            /*i'm not sure what this but is kind of a dialogue of what came first and later, You must previously assign the ViewController Identity on the "StoryBoard ID" it will help any doubt or image help contact me*/
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                var Storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                var PerfilUsuario : UIViewController = Storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PerfilUsuario") as! UIViewController
                self.presentViewController(PerfilUsuario, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
        else {
            TrekLogo.hidden = true
        }
}
```

well i hope it can't help you now i will try with the internet login 
[well the is the section of the "StoryBoard ID" on the top right, look for "UsuarioPerfil" There](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTcjS.png)

Answer (score 0):

well!!! i had done sorry for my english, but here is my final code with parse Login it always say " Variable "variableName" Was never mutated but it work if you could help me with that....

```
    @IBAction func LoginPressed(sender: UIButton) {

        var User = PFUser()

        User.username = RutField.text
        User.password = CodigoField.text

        PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(RutField.text!, password: CodigoField.text!, block:{(User : PFUser?, Error : NSError?) -> Void in

            if Error == nil {

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                    var Storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                    var PerfilUsuario : UIViewController = Storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PerfilUsuario") as! UIViewController
                    self.presentViewController(PerfilUsuario, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
            else {
                self.TrekLogo.hidden = true
            }
        })


}
```

i hope it could help